# Update a layer from QGIS DB manager

Tags: qgis, database

I have a  layer that I want to upgrade using SQL sentences with QGIS DB manager. I want to do a simple join with another table, both are in a geopackage.

My question is: Can I update the point layer that I'm using for the join without necessary load a new layer?

I know is possibly using the interface of QGIS in proprieties > joins but I want to know if it's possible to do the same with the DB manager.

Comment: If they are in the _same_ GPKG, sure?

Comment: yes, they are in the same GPKG